# Why doesn't this higher-order function pass static type checking in mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, mypy

I'm trying to get to grips with mypy. As an exercise, I'm trying to figure out the right type annotations for some common higher-order functions. But I don't quite understand why the following code doesn't type check.

**test.py**

```py
from typing import Iterable, TypeVar, Callable

T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')

def chain(
        functions: Iterable[Callable[[T1], T1]]
    ) -> Callable[[T1], T1]:

    def compose(
            f: Callable[[T1], T1],
            g: Callable[[T1], T1]
        ) -> Callable[[T1], T1]:
        def h(x: T1) -> T1:
            return g(f(x))
        return h

    def identity(x: T1) -> T1:
        return x

    return reduce(functions, compose, identity)

def reduce(
        items: Iterable[T1], 
        op:    Callable[[T2, T1], T2],
        init:  T2
    ) -> T2:
    for item in items:
        init = op(init, item)
    return init

def add_one(x):
    return x + 1

def mul_two(x):
    return x * 2

assert chain([add_one, mul_two, mul_two, add_one])(7) == 33
```

The code runs correctly in python, but `mypy test.py` produces the following error message (I've formatted it slightly for readability):

```
test.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "reduce" has incompatible type
"Callable[
  [Arg(Callable[[T1], T1], 'f'), Arg(Callable[[T1], T1], 'g')],
  Callable[[T1], T1]
]"; 
expected 
"Callable[
  [Callable[[T1], T1], Callable[[T1], T1]], 
  Callable[[T1], T1]
]"
```

I'm not sure where `Arg` is coming from. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation for `typing`, and the [only reference](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/additional_features.html#extended-callable-types) to it in the mypy documentation says that it is a deprecated feature.

My only thought is that it might have something to do with the fact that `compose` produces a closure.

This is mypy version `0.720` and Python version `3.7.3`.

---

### Update

So it seems as if the error message might be misleading.  After adding the following code, the error disappears:

```py
from typing import overload

@overload
def reduce(
        items: Iterable[T1],
        op:    Callable[[T1, T1], T1],
        init:  T1
    ) -> T1: ...

@overload
def reduce(
        items: Iterable[T1],
        op:    Callable[[T2, T1], T2],
        init:  T2
    ) -> T2: ...
```

But it's still not clear to me what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange issue, which seems to be a [bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9810), because `pytype` and `pyre` correctly checks your code.

Mypy fails with your code but successfully checks the code if you change your `identity` function to:

```
def identity(x: T1, /) -> T1:
  return x
```

The only difference is that the function now only accepts [positional arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/).

Note, I'd use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) instead, so that you can leverage typings from typeshed. In that case you would need to call `return reduce(compose, functions, identity)`.

BONUS:
There's also a strange [`pyre` issue](https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check/issues/357), if you move the `identity` function outside `compose`, then I get an error

```
 Mutually recursive type variables [36]: Solving type variables for call `reduce` led to infinite recursion.
```

But get fixed if you replace your `reduce` with `functools.reduce`.